# Moving the date in amsart

Tags: titles, amsart

I am using the `amsart` documentclass. I use `\maketitle` at the beginning of my file:

```
\date{\today}
\maketitle
```

The problem is that `amsart` places the date in a footnote at the bottom of the first page, and I want the date to appear at the top of the page, under the author (where the date would appear using the `article` documentclass). Is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 9):

A simpler way to patch the `\maketitle` command in **amsart** is

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}
  {\ifx\@empty\@dedicatory}
  {\ifx\@empty\@date \else {\vskip3ex \centering\footnotesize\@date\par\vskip1ex}\fi
   \ifx\@empty\@dedicatory}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@adminfootnotes}
  {\ifx\@empty\@date\else \@footnotetext{\@setdate}\fi}
  {}{}{}
\makeatother
```

The spirit is just the same as Schweinebacke's answer, but this code doesn't require to copy the entire definition of `\@maketitle` and `\@adminfootnotes`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to use at least `\undefined` at the last argument of `\patchcmd` to get an error, if the patch fails, e.g., because of a typo mistake or change at `amsart`?

Comment: I have a quick question sir. After I apply your code, yes, the data indeed appears at the top of the page. However, there is another data which is stay at the place of footnote. (that is, there are two 'datas' in the front page). Could you fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You may use the standard class article with additional packages [amsthm](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm), [mathtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools), and maybe [amsrefs](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsrefs) to have a standard class with most features of the AMS classes but standard class lookalike.

Alternative you may use `amsart` and combine it with the title definition of article:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\maketitle{\par
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
    \def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}%
    \long\def\@makefntext##1{\parindent 1em\noindent
            \hb@xt@1.8em{%
                \hss\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}##1}%
    \if@twocolumn
      \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
        \@maketitle
      \else
        \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
      \fi
    \else
      \newpage
      \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
      \@maketitle
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}\@thanks
  \endgroup
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}
\renewcommand*\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\renewcommand{\author}[1]{\gdef\@author{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{title}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Or you may redefine only `\@maketitle` of `amsart`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@maketitle{%
  \normalfont\normalsize
  \@adminfootnotes
  \@mkboth{\@nx\shortauthors}{\@nx\shorttitle}%
  \global\topskip42\p@\relax % 5.5pc   "   "   "     "     "
  \@settitle
  \ifx\@empty\authors \else \@setauthors \fi
  \ifx\@empty\@date \else {\vskip 1em \vtop{\centering\large\@date\@@par}}\fi% MY CHANGE
  \ifx\@empty\@dedicatory
  \else
    \baselineskip18\p@
    \vtop{\centering{\footnotesize\itshape\@dedicatory\@@par}%
      \global\dimen@i\prevdepth}\prevdepth\dimen@i
  \fi
  \@setabstract
  \normalsize
  \if@titlepage
    \newpage
  \else
    \dimen@34\p@ \advance\dimen@-\baselineskip
    \vskip\dimen@\relax
  \fi
} % end \@maketitle
\renewcommand*\@adminfootnotes{%
  \let\@makefnmark\relax  \let\@thefnmark\relax
%  \ifx\@empty\@date\else \@footnotetext{\@setdate}\fi% MY CHANGE
  \ifx\@empty\@subjclass\else \@footnotetext{\@setsubjclass}\fi
  \ifx\@empty\@keywords\else \@footnotetext{\@setkeywords}\fi
  \ifx\@empty\thankses\else \@footnotetext{%
    \def\par{\let\par\@par}\@setthanks}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{title}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I've marked my changes of the original definitions of `amsart` at this alternative with comments `% MY CHANGE`.

But if you want a title page instead of a in page title head, have also a look at [Resources for title page and front matter design](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35018/resources-for-title-page-and-front-matter-design/35023#35023).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and here's what I did:

```
\author{Name Here\\\today}
```

It looks good, putting the date right below the author in the same font, but it could fail if you have any macros lying around that depend on your title.

If you want this to feel less ad hoc, you could put

```
% in the preamble or class file
\def\customauthor{\empty}
\def\customdate{\empty}
\let\oldauthor\author
\renewcommand{\author}[1]{\def\customauthor{#1}}
\renewcommand{\date}[1]{\def\customdate{#1}}
\oldauthor{\customauthor\\\customdate}

% and then, just as usual:
\author{Name Here}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
```

Though this is a little more complicated, it's more flexible, in case you need to change it later.