# Book cover, integration multilayered equations. (Suggestions?)

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles, book-design

I am sort of writing a compendium about integration, everyhting from basic substitutions, to contour integrals, Gamma, beta integrals and so forth.

I feel that no standard frontcase suffices and I therefore think that the best solution for a bookcover would be using tikz (correct?)

I was thinking about tinting the page slightly gray. And making it similar to the headliner here. Some centered text, and then some faded multilayered equations and images

[image: My idea for a bookcase]

Now, the equations should be a mixture between integrals, and images. Things like

[image: Navier stokes Equation]

[image: Sphere]

[image: Error integral]

[image: Long Equation]

[image: Gaussian integral]

[image: Complex integral 1]

[image]

[image: One of my favourite integrals]

[image: Another one of my favourite integrals]

[image]

*My question is, how would one go about creating such  a titlepage? My problem is adding the multilayered equations, in different shades.*

(If someone has some arguments or ideas for a better frontpage, I am all ears.)

Comment: Check out chapter 20 of the TikZ manual for information on transparency. You can simply use the `fill opacity=0.x` option on a node to make it more or less transparent. The other elements you could put in a scope and apply an opacity setting on that. For layers have a look at chapter 82 of the manual.

Comment: And for what it's worth, use upright d's in your integrals, it should be `\,\mathrm{d}x` (or something similar, I've seen sans-serif for instance), not `dx` :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There has been a related (but less specific) question a couple of days ago: [Resources for title page and front matter design](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35018/resources-for-title-page-and-front-matter-design), where I suggested the somewhat prosaic approach: Do not use LaTeX for the cover, but some good vector drawing program. Export it to PDF and employ `pdfpages`, `\includegraphics` or `pdftk` to add it to the document.

I think, your cover is a perfect showcase for this approach:

- It is just a one-time thing!
- You are seeking a very visual, arty design. Crafting it will probably be a process of visual trial-and-error with many iterations, until you are satisfied.

Doing this with LaTeX / TikZ might be fun, but it certainly will be an enormous time sink: I am a big fan of "use the right tool for the task"; if  the task is mostly about visual effects and only marginally about structured content, I would say that a visual tool is better suited than LaTeX.

As your cover involves many formulas, for which typesetting LaTeX is just great, I would probably go for a mixture:

1. Use LaTeX to produce the "basic elements" of your cover, that is, the title, equations, graphs, symbols, whatever. (Use the [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) class or, if you are on a Mac, a tool like [LaTeXiT](http://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-home.php) to transform them into PDF or EPS images.)
2. Use a good vector drawing program (Inkscape, Illustrator) to layout, blend, shade, ... these elements in order to craft the resulting cover page.

Answer (score 8):

You can as has been pointed out use the `fill opacity`, `opacity` and the `text opacity` for your free disposal while drawing and get the wanted effect from that.

In your use of `tikz` I would recommend to use the `overlay` feature which is really nice when specifying absolute positions on a page (and in the matter of a frontpage this could be highly desirable). I have added here a small example that will give you an idea of setting it up and doing it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \begin{scope}[shift=(current page.center)]
    \node[scale=2,opacity=0.8] at (-1,2) {$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac x \hbar \,\mathrm dx$};
    \begin{scope}[opacity=0.4]
      \draw (3,0) node[below] {$a$} arc (0:180:3cm) node[below] {$b$} -- cycle;
      \fill (0,0.3) circle (2pt) node[right] {$i$};
    \end{scope}
    \node[opacity=0.45] at (-.9,-2.5) 
    {$\displaystyle S(x)=\int_0^x\sin(t^2)\,\mathrm dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{4n+3}}{(2n+1)!(4n+3)}$};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage
Start my book...
\end{document}
```

With this setup you start on the center of the page and define everything from that place. This could come in handy, notice the first `scope` block.
Of course you can optimise the `\displaystyle` away in your preferable manor.

Answer (score 2):

You can also play with [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/). There is one plugin to insert LaTeX equations : [textext](http://pav.iki.fi/software/textext/).