# How to include information about title, author, publisher on a title page?

Tags: titles

EDIT: Border is not part of the final result - it's just a screenshot.

I want my title page (first page after cover) to look like this (taken from word document):

[image]

What is the proper way of laying out a title page?
Should I use the `title`, `author` commands, or just layout text with `vspace` and such? However, I don't know if LaTeX has fields for specifying `publisher` and `publisher place`.

Any tips or examples on how to do this would be great.

Comment: Title pages can be designed using the `titlepage` environment. There's no provision for fields such as "publisher", as it would be impossible to foresee all kind of data one wants to put in a title page. Code it as you like.

Comment: I rephrased your question title to make it a better fit for this site. As it was, it would've been _too localized_, but I think you're actually asking a legitimate and interesting question.

Comment: Possible ducplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35018/resources-for-title-page-and-front-matter-design

Comment: @egreg, JFTR: drozzy didn’t provide an MWE, so we don’t know, whether he (if the picture doesn’t lie) uses `KOMA-script`, where a `\publishers` title macro is provided, which on the other hand does not help the OP, because it is set together with the other fields (not as deep as the drozzy wishes) – it seems to me, it is meant for the editor(s).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you type `texdoc titlepages` in a command line, you should find Peter Wilson's wonderful set of title page examples.  Here's the link on CTAN: [TitlePages](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/latex-samples/TitlePages).

Comment: Wow, that looks wonderful. Should give me some good reading :-)

Comment: The examples are so hard to figure out... I don't know which commands are the standard ones, and which ones are defined by the author...

Comment: @drozzy There's a basic set of commands at the beginning of the code examples which is common to all the examples. Then for each example, there is some extra code for that particular format. Also, since Peter Wilson is the author of the `memoir` class, you might want to look at its documentation.  Memoir is excellent for book length projects. You might also want to look into using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX which have easier font selection capabilities than standard LaTeX.

Comment: Alan, somewhere I /had/ to write this, so it’s mot meant offensive against you: The tip with `texdoc` does not every time work with MiKTeX, especially the info section of CTAN is barely included, but also some packages are not. So a link to CTAN as you did is always welcome.

Comment: @Speravir Thanks for mentioning this.  I've been told this before, too. :-) I forget that not everyone uses TeXLive. (And even then, perhaps some people have less than complete distributions installed.)

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure whether the border is there in your title. Have a look at this. Hope it is useful.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{titlepage}
%=========================
\begin{center}
\hspace{0pt}\\
\vspace{4cm}
{\Large\bfseries ANDRIY DROZDYUK}\\[5pt]
{\Large\bfseries DENYS DROZDYUK}\\
\vspace{3cm}
 {\scalebox{2}{\Huge\bfseries FIBONACCI,}}\\
\vspace{0.8cm}
 {\LARGE\bfseries HIS NUMBERS AND HIS}\\[10pt]
 {\LARGE\bfseries RABBITS}\\
 % ----------------------------------------------------------------
 \vfill
 Choven Publishing Company\\
 TORONTO--2010
 % ----------------------------------------------------------------
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Ops, nope, border should not be part of it.

Comment: @drozzy I have now removed the border.

Comment: Are you sure this will work for differently sized layouts?

Comment: @drozzy If I know your particular layout I can figure it out. Any how you can change the sizes using the geometry package mentioned in my code (i.e., change the margins and paper size). It will be helpful if you give details of your layout.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the great reference Alan's referring to, I recommend just hard-coding your title page as you like. You can use the `titlepage` environment, but I don't find it to be particularly useful (see [What does the titlepage environment do and what are its benefits?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27543/4012)). You can access the information stored in `\title` and `\author` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\author{Frank Foo}
\title{Bar Baz}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\@author: \@title
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Or you can use the `titling` package, which stores this information in macros:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titling}

\author{Frank Foo}
\title{Bar Baz}

\begin{document}

\theauthor: \thetitle

\end{document}
```

For vertical alignment, I recommend using `\vspace*{\fill}`, which puts elements maximally far apart, e.g. if you want to put *Choven Publishing Corp.* etc. at the very bottom of your page.

If you want to vertically space out elements, but leave different amounts of space, you can use `\vspace*{\stretch{n}}`, e.g.

```
Foo

\vspace*{\stretch{1}}

Bar

\vspace*{\stretch{2}}

Baz
```

This gives you double the amount of space between *Bar* and *Baz* that you have between *Foo* and *Bar*. You can use any numbers you like, of course.

If you want to put elemtents next to each other (e.g. some text and a logo), `minipage`s will be your friend. There's a question about that somewhere here, which I couldn't find right now, but I'll insert the link if I come across it again.

Finally, as you implied in your question, it's good to use `\vspace` or `\vspace*` to add vertical space; don't use several instances of `\\`.