# titlepage with article class

Tags: titles, article

I use `article` document class and want to make a titlepage. But I need to put more than just author, year and title. I also need to put my university and my supervisor and that is my bachelor thesis. If I just write it there without anything like `\author{}`, in the `.pdf` it's on the page before the title page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
 Bachelorarbeit

\begin{center}
University
\end{center}

\title{Title}

\author{Frida}

supervisor: Prof XY

\date{\today}

\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See [What does the `titlepage` environment do and what are its benefits?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27543/5764) It's not really necessary to use the `titlepage` environment, as is given in the answer.

Comment: May be useful: [How to include information about title, author, publisher on a title page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46774) , [Custom title page in report or book class?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59466) . These can be adapted to `article` class also.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why don't rewrite your frontispiece from scratch without the use of `\maketitle` inside `titlepage`?

I mean something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
  \bfseries
  \huge UNIVERSITY OF \ldots
  \vskip.2in
  \textsc{\LARGE Faculty of \ldots}
  \vskip.2in
  \large Department of \ldots
  \vskip1in
  \Large Bachelorarbeit
  \vskip1.5in
  \emph{\huge Title}
\end{center}

\vskip1.4in

\begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
  \begin{flushleft}
    \bfseries\large Supervisor:\par \emph{Prof. XY}
  \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\hskip.4\textwidth
\begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
  \begin{flushleft}
    \bfseries\large Student:\par \emph{Frida}
  \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}

\vskip1.3in

\centering
\bfseries
\Large Year \the\year
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

which looks like (adapt to your needs):

[image]