# Add additional text on title page

Tags: formatting, titles

I want my title page to look like this

```
                                Title
                                Author
                                Date
          Coordinator1                          Coordinator2
                          Dept. of Physics
                            ABC College
```

If I put some text after `\maketitle`, it gets shifted to next page. How can I add this to same page? Is there any way of doing this (except writing the whole title page on my own)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `titlepage` environment.

Comment: Add the option `notitlepage` to your `\documentclass` and issue a `\newpage` after `ABC College`. For the future: Please always add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. As your question is right now, you're forcing us to do a lot of guesswork.

Comment: most importantly, what document class are you using?

Comment: You can also just redefine what `\maketitle` does. See my example below

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a quick way by means of a `\date` hijacking:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering%
  \today\endgraf\bigskip
  Coordinator 1 \hspace*{3cm} Coordinator 2\endgraf\medskip
  Dept.\ of Physics \endgraf
  ABC College}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The reason for being able to do this is because the title macros (`\title`, `\author` and `\date`) can contain anything, as long as it's not paragraphs. `\endgraf` is okay though.

Of course, it is not that difficult to create your own, non-standard title page using other means (like the `titlepage` environment). For more on this, see [Resources for title page and front matter design](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35018/5764).

Comment: Thanks,worked for me.But one more issue.If i try to increase hspace between 'Coordinator1' and 'Coordinator2', Coordinator2's text alignment changes(wrapping).Is this because I have used the full width of the page ?

Comment: @abhi120: Yes. If you use more than `\linewidth` (or `\textwidth`), wrapping will occur. Since I don't know the extent to which it overlaps or the actual content, I would need more information to adequately recommend an alternative solution.

Comment: There are better ways of achieving the same thing without messing with predefined text fields.

Comment: @Superuser27: Sure thing! There are always better ways of doing things, depending on your situation.

Comment: I am getting weird TeX errors if I change the Coordinator line too much.  For example, this works: `E1\hspace*{0cm}\endgraf\medskip`, but if I make it `English\hspace*{0cm}\endgraf\medskip`, then I get ! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.  Any ideas?

Comment: In fact just deleting the "1" from  "Coordinator 1" triggers this error.   It's absolutely repeatable - put back the 1 and the error goes away.

Answer (score 12):

You can just redefine the `maketitle` to do whatever you want. In the example below feel free to tweak the spacing and font styles to change them to whatever you like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
\begin{center}

\pagestyle{empty}
\phantom{.}  %necessary to add space on top before the title
\vspace{3cm}

{\Huge \bf \@title\par}
\vspace{2.5cm}

{\LARGE Your Name}\\[1cm]

{\Large\@date}

\vspace{4.5cm}
{\Large Advisor 1}\hspace{2cm}{\Large Advisor 2}\\[2cm]
Dept. of Foo\\
ABC College
%if you want something in the bottom of the page just use \vfill before that.

\end{center}
}\makeatother


\title{Your great title}  % you can actually insert these directly above if you prefer.
\date{March 2019}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: That should be \vfill, not /vfill.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Keith