# Enter text below \author and above \begin{document}

Tags: titles

I need to write text just below the name of the author but before the document begins. I think I'm dealing with the title page here. I'm fairly new to using Latex and I don't exactly know how to go about this. I'm using `\documentclass{report}`. Please help.

Comment: Your title is misleading. You want to put some extra text on the titlepage, but *not* before `\begin{document}`, but before the remaining document content starts ;-)

Comment: do you use the `titlepage` option? In that case, the title page could be redefined.
Please improve the question by adding a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) or at lease a screenshot of what you want to  achieve

Comment: @FriedNoodles have you looked into this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63384/add-additional-text-on-title-page

Comment: You may take a look at the `titling` package which helps customising the `\maketitle`command.