# Weird behavior in \date field

Tags: titles, parbox

I'm trying to "trick" the date field in \maketitle into allowing me an extra line to link to the latest version of my paper. I borrowed an example from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63385/66764), and it works. However, when I try to edit it, I get weird behavior. I tried to just delete all the placeholder text and add my own, as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titling}

\title{Title}
 \author{Me}

\date{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
  \today\endgraf\medskip
Please click {\color{blue}\href{[[link]]}{here}} for the latest version of this paper.}}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

(I have a real working link in lieu of [[link]]. Removing the \href command altogether changes nothing) However, this gives me the following error:

```
! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
```

What does work, bizarrely enough, is just adding a "1" before "Please":

```
\date{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
\today\endgraf\medskip
1Please click {\color{blue}\href{[[link]]}{here}} for the latest version of this paper.}
}
```

This compiles fine, although it gives me an extraneous "1" that I'd rather not have.

Does anyone know where this behavior is coming from?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site.  However, please provide a small but complete working example that shows the problem, beginning with `\documentclass`.

Comment: Hi @StevenB.Segletes, I edited the first code block to make it workable. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you load titling and then don't use it?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titling}

\title{Title}
 \author{Me}
\date{\today}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookd{\noindent\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering Please blblblb}}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a very good question. Thanks! This works perfectly!